# Minimizing RSS in linear regression

Tags: regression, self-study, mathematical-statistics, linear

Assume that I want to estimate the coefficients in a linear regression model by minimizing the RSS for the first $p$, where $p<P$, regressors:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \left( y_i - \beta_0 - \sum_{j=1}^p \beta_j x_{ij} \right)^2 $$

I want to know the following as to what happens if I increase $p$ from $1$ to $P$,(maximum number of regressors, to the following,

a) the training RSS
b) test MSE
c) squared bias
d) variance
e) irreducible error

I have four options which can occur to each either 
i) remain constant
ii) steadily increase
iii) steadily decrease
iv) either increase/decrease initially, and then later start decreasing/increasing in an inverted/noninverted U shape.

Can you please assist with this as I am not sure how this would impact any parts in a-e as the $p$ is located in the $\sum$ part of this question.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What have you learned about overfitting in linear regression? What have you learned  about the bias-variance trade-off in modeling?

Comment: @EdM Alright, so if I am understanding this correctly. It's essentially asking what will happen in each case as we increase the number of regressors on our model.

Comment: That expression is the loss function (square loss). The regression equation is $\hat{y}_i = \beta_0+\sum_{j=1}^p\beta_j x_{ij}$. (The $\beta$s should have hats on them, too, as they are estimated.)

Comment: Your understanding is my understanding of the question. Start with 1 predictor, then add in another and describe what's likely to happen to training RSS, test MSE, squared bias, variance, and irreducible error. Continue adding in one predictor at a time. I suspect that the question is intended to go up to a reasonably high maximum number of predictors $P$. This seems to be trying to get you to think about the [bias-variance tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias–variance_tradeoff). [This book](http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/) has a nice description starting on page 33.